# Is it possible to get a transient SSL error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, haproxy

In production we got an exception thrown which is pretty self-explanatory: `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`.

However, it appears to have been totally transient - except for this one exception the servers are communicating over `SSL` fine and the certificate is valid when you inspect it in a browser. It looks like a one-off.

It was my understanding that such an error could not be transient as it could only be due to something tangible and permanent like an expired/missing `SSL` certificate.

Is it possible to have a transient `SSL` error or is this a red herring?

For what it's worth the calling code is `asp.net` and the certificate-bearing server is a load-balancer running `HA Proxy` (with two web servers sat behind it but we are doing SSL termination at the balancer).

Answer (score 0):

Transient errors are possible during the SSL handshake too. It might be for example that the load balancer just closes the connection during SSL handshake, when it temporarily cannot reach the backend server.